# How to show product detail on homepage

Tags: product

I have try to search, but I did not get any suitable suggestion or solution.
I want to have on my frontpage detail of product (I mean this: http://community.user.magentotrial.com/asicsr-men-s-gel-kayanor-xii-95.html on homepage).
Have you any suggestion, or idea, or even extension (I did not find suitable extension).
I want, that visitor can directly choose attributes and buy product, he do not need go to product detail page - so detail page is first, what you will see after opening my site url.

// I forgot my installation is 1.9.0.1 (demo is 1.8 but does not matter, it is just to imagine what I mean)

Thank you very much Peter

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Magento rewrite rule to show the product page when the homepage is called.

First navigate to the backend menu `Catalog` > `Manage products`. Find your product in the grid and find the `ID` of your product in the first column (e.g. 1).

Go to `Catalog` > `URL Rewrite Management`. Click on `Add URL Rewrite`. When asked which kind of URL rewrite you want to create (For category, For product, Custom) choose `Custom`.

Next, enter this information:

[image: URL rewrite settings]

- The `ID Path` is just a unique name/identifier for this rewrite.
- The `Request Path` is the path that is initially requested by the user (`/` is pretty much the same as the homepage).
- `Target Path` is the action that will be called. The `1` in the end is the product ID so replace 1 with whatever your product ID is.
- Setting `Redirect` to `No` means that your browser will not be redirected to the URL `catalog/product/view/id/1` but will stay at the homepage URL. If you set this to `301` or `302` the URL will change.

Please note that though I did a quick test and it worked for me you should check it with all possible scenarios in your peculiar shop in a test instance to make sure it doesn't break anything. Also take into consideration that it may hurt your search engine ranking if you have the exactly same information on the homepage and on the product page itself.

Comment: Hi Matthias, thank you for explanation. It works and of course I will use it, if I will not find any better solution.

Comment: send before I finish: Just explanation: I will still sell only one product, but limited time. After that time, product will go just to "After Sell", and new product come to his place. So I will do not have category link on my pages to category with product and also mean, that customer does not need to click category, then product to get view of product, that is reason, why I want to have product on main page. With this solution, I will change every time ID. May be exist better solution, but thanks.